# ruby hash-table insert new element with existing key

Tags: ruby, hashtable

Say I have a array of words, different words might have different lengths, and I want to organise them by length. So later I can access all words share with same length by giving a parameter of length.

```
words = Array.new()
#fill words by reading file

words.each do |word|
    #add word to hash table, key is the length of this word
    #what can I do?
end
```

I have check other questions and answers in stack overflow but none of them are telling how to insert a new value under the old key while keep all of them in a array form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After reading the words from the file, you can use `group_by` to create a hash:

```
data = %w[one two three four five six seven eight nine ten]
hash = data.group_by{ |w| w.size }
```

At that point, `hash` is:

```
{
    3 => [
        [0] "one",
        [1] "two",
        [2] "six",
        [3] "ten"
    ],
    5 => [
        [0] "three",
        [1] "seven",
        [2] "eight"
    ],
    4 => [
        [0] "four",
        [1] "five",
        [2] "nine"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Or, as always, `group_by(&:size)`.

Comment: I'm still on the fence about using the proc-symbols in example code. Just when I think it's safe someone pops up running 1.8 and doesn't admit it. :-/

Comment: @theTinMan as you may now, ruby18 it's deprecated and no longer supported. http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2011/10/06/plans-for-1-8-7/ IMHO I think we should forget about people using 1.8 ^_^

Comment: That may be so, but 1.8.7 is installed on an incredible number of machines that people don't have the ability or rights to upgrade to something newer. I support a number of CentOS hosts that only have 1.8.6 and 1.8.7 so I automatically install a 1.9.3 version for our development/production use, but many aren't that privileged.

Answer (score 0):

```
%w(he is a good man).inject({}){|temp,ob| temp[ob.length] ||= [];temp[ob.length] = (temp[ob.length] + [ob]);temp}
```

*Output:*

```
{2=>["he", "is"], 1=>["a"], 4=>["good"], 3=>["man"]}
```

---

```
require 'pp'
pp %w[one two three four five six seven eight nine ten].inject({}){|temp,ob| temp[ob.length] ||= [];temp[ob.length] = (temp[ob.length] + [ob]);temp}
```

*Output:*

```
{3=>["one", "two", "six", "ten"],
 5=>["three", "seven", "eight"],
 4=>["four", "five", "nine"]}
```

Comment: thanks, but this is little difficult for me to understand, I need to learn more ruby grammar.